how to adjust cutoff in a logistic regression model?
example contrived for this question.
I am training a binary classifier utilizing sklearn package. I have a balanced dataset, half positive and half negative samples. I split the train/test data (sample code below). I want to train this, such that I have good enough precision and recall values. I definitely want to have more false positive than false negatitve. I understand I can adjust cutoff value, and that cutoff value can impact precision and accuracy of my model. Is it a good strategy to adjust cutoff during training, until you get desired precision recall value?
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=16)

logreg = LogisticRegression()

logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)


Not during training, but after it. then your model ouputs a value between 0 and 1 for how sure it is that it is a negative (more towards 0) or positive (more towards 1) sample. There you can see how the precision/recall change using the set of values you get from the model and transforming them into binary decisions for each value of threshold you consider.
The most straight forward way is to use a ROC (receiving operator characteristic) https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html
which takes your y_pred, the true labels, and returns the false positive and false negative rates for a series of possible thresholds, which you can then plot to select which ratio of FP/FN works better for you, which corresponds to a specific threshold choice.
